# namespace reservations

Tags: wcf, http, installshield

I have created a stand-alone wcf JSON service (port 4326). On Windows 7, I find that either I have to run as admin, or use the netsh as a command line (just once) to unblock the port:

```
e.g. C:> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:4326/ user=CSDL-SERVICES\ysg4206
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx

Is there a way that I could do this from within the .NET application (so that the user does not have to do it after installing the program? Can I discover the user account, and do this permanently like the netsh program?

Alternatively, is there some way in InstallShield to find out the domain/username of the user and then run this as a script during install?

Comment: I gave some pointers despite the low probability of an accepted answer. (Par for the course on the InstallShield tag.)

Comment: Chris, actually, you helped already, just by indicating that it is probably clener and better to do this in the intaller, than figuring out how to do it in the .NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What InstallShield version and project type are you using?

If MSI, you could use an EXE custom action to run that command.  Another option would be an InstallScript custom action calling LaunchAppAndWait to call the EXE. (No flashing DOS prompt.)

Also, if MSI, you could create a WiX merge module that either uses the Quiet Execute Custom Action pattern or possibly the Firewall Extension.

[FirewallException Element (Firewall Extension)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/firewall_xsd_firewallexception.htm)

[Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm)

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

[LaunchAppAndWait](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15langref/LangrefLaunchAppAndWait.htm)

[Q102426: HOWTO: Launch a Custom Executable](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q102426)

Comment: I am using Spring 2012 PRO. So what I am looking at is running a Powershell script at the end which will run netsh.exe (powershell lets me do things like Get-ChildItem Env:UserName ). Now I just need to figure how to elevate to ADMIN privileges from inside a PowerShell script. (netsh.exe requires admin in WIN7). Does this make sense?

Comment: Not really.  Windows Installer has properties such as [UserName] that can be used to pass.  But your username would be SYSTEM since it's an elevated custom action.  You'd really want to pass the property that was used in the ServiceInstall table to create the service.